# Webpack-dev-server ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined error while running ReactJS app. Checked few other similar questions but not able to resolve the issue. It seems like issue with "webpack-dev-server/client/modules/logger/index.js" but not 100%. I am looking for some hints which might be helpful to resolve the issue because It might not be reproducible. Can it we be a issue with Package.json or webpack config file?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (index.js:776:1)
    at eval (index.js:782:2)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/modules/logger/index.js (vendors-68328274fd40ddcb272a.bundle.js:25950:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime-65873e61fb5776d342f6.bundle.js:36:33)
    at fn (runtime-65873e61fb5776d342f6.bundle.js:291:21)
    at eval (log.js:7:82)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js (vendors-68328274fd40ddcb272a.bundle.js:26049:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime-65873e61fb5776d342f6.bundle.js:36:33)
    at fn (runtime-65873e61fb5776d342f6.bundle.js:291:21)
    at eval (WebSocketClient.js:6:71)
```

Comment: Create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example